# One-to-One ids must be manually assigned

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I wonder how to make Hibernate cascade ids when saving one-to-one entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "foo_seq")
    private Integer fooId;

    // ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "foo")
    private Bar bar;

    // ...

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bat;
        if (bar != null) {
            bar.setFoo(this);
            bar.setFooId(getFooId());
        }
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
class Bar {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    // this is the foo's id, the foreign key is the primary key of this table
    private Integer fooId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Foo foo;

    // ...

}
```

Well, when I save a instance of `Foo` without `Bar`, then set an instance of `Bar` and save it again it works, but if I try to save it all once it says `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save`.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
// foo.set...
repository.save(foo); // I do not want to save twice, I want to remove it
Bar bar = new Bar();
// bar.set...
foo.setBar(bar);
repository.save(foo);
```

How can I fix this issue? I do not need it to be bidirectional, but this must be possible to get a `Bar` from a `Foo`, like discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517989/onetoone-bidirectional-mapping-foreign-key-auto-fill), but this time the id is the same from Foo table.

Comment: use **sequence** as GenerationType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its behaving like this is because Hibernate is generating the value of **fooId** at the time it is saving the Entity and not before that. So even if you are assigning the **fooId** in `setBar()` method its actually assigning `NULL` to the `Bar.fooId` and since you haven't defined and **Generation Strategy** on **Bar.fooId** you are getting that error. Modify Bar class as given below and then try again and that error should go away:

```
 @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer fooId;
```